# Needs to enable left pane fields palette along with anchor tagging

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect

We are using DocuSign embedded signing and set up some anchor tags(using anchorString) for directing user to signing places . But we want to be more flexible by enabling left panel field palettes also available when anchor tagging in place .

Is there any way I can use custom tags(anchor tagging) along with left field palettes by adding some extra configuration( using C#).

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Subin

Answer (score 1):

I directly posted same query in DocuSign community and got below response .

> The left panel is known as Freeform Signing, this appears when a document with no fields is placed (which puts the recipient into a free-form signing experience). Since the tabs are available (due to anchor tagging), then you won't have the Freeform Signing panel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).